# excluding port from VPN client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, vpn, iptables

I use hidemyass which is a vpn service. I use it for privacy reasons. The main purpose of the VPN is for my web browsing.

How can I exclude certain ports from using the VPN connection? For example: I upload files using ftp and when I'm connected to my VPN service, I don't want the ftp client to use the VPN connection but I want it to use my main internet connection. From the research I have done, it seems I need to configure ip tables so it would exclude port 21 from the VPN connection. how would I configure it? In using Ubuntu as my os.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this would be quite difficult - particularly with a service like FTP.  If you know where you are FTP'ing to it might be a lot easier to simply push the routes out the appropriate interface.

If you really need to do it the hard way it envolves setting up policy based routing and SNAT which is a pain in the neck - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port

So in essence you need to set up 2 network tables - one for the VPN, one for the real network.  You then use iptables to tag the packets and direct them to the appropriate interface.

There is a 2 part step-by-step tutorial which is very similar to what you are looking at at 
http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/DualIdentityRouting and
http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/ForcingOutgoingInterface

Unfortunately you can't just use an IPTABLES SNAT rule because the traffic will leave the wrong interface even though you can adjust the from IP address.